# Как получить данные из строки listview

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview

Имеется элемент `listview`, с нескольким количеством строк, как считать строки? (с выбранными проще можно воспользоваться `Selected`'ом)?

Заполняю так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyReaderData.TagList.TotalTags; i++)
{   
    string[] sItems = new string[] 
    {
        i.ToString(), 
        MyReaderData.TagList[i].ToString(),     
    };

    this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(sItems));
 }
```

Потом через `foreach` хочу считать один введенный параметр, и считать элементы `listview` и передать их в процедуру, которая в свою очередь запишет их в БД *MS SQL*.

```
foreach (ListViewItems it in ReaderDataListView.Items)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@var1", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@var1"].Value = Int32.Parse(tbVar1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@var2", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@var2"].Value = it.Items.ToString();
    DataTable dt = programm1.SqlCon.sqlproc("dbo.testTable", cmd);
}
```

Если пытаюсь считать элемент таким образом то получаю индекс(т.к порядковый номер элемента `0`,`1` и т.д). Как получить именно значение из строки `listview`?

**Разобрался, обращаться нужно так:**

```
cmd.Parameters["@var2"].Value = it.SubItems[1].Text;
```

Comment: WinForms или WPF? И какая ваша реальная задача?

Comment: Разобрался к элементу listview надо было обращаться: 

cmd.Parameters["@var2"].Value = it.SubItems[1].Text;

P.S. VladD спасибо за быстрый ответ. WinForms. Задача маркировка rfid-метками.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] sItem = new string[]
    {
        "idx","Value"
    };               

ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(sItem);    
MessageBox.Show( it.SubItems[1].Text);
```

Получишь "Value"

Вот тут замени:
`foreach (ListViewItems it in ...` на

```
foreach (ListViewItem it in ...
```

и
`cmd.Parameters["@var2"].Value = it.Items.ToString();` на

```
...Value = it.SubItems[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Спасибо, дошел до этого уже сам. 

Пробовал SubItems.Text и получал бред. Потом увидел что у меня ж массив, и обратился к элементу правильно